# Output more than 1 datatables in shiny main panel

Tags: r, for-loop, shiny, lapply, dt

I have a shiny app that a user can check whether they want the data table displayed in the main panel. Depending on the numericinput, if they select 1, only 1 datatable be displayed or if they select 2 it will display 2 datatables I am not so sure how to code this in shiny R since I am new to this. Thank you for looking into this.
Here is my code

```
library("shiny")
df1 <- data.frame("2010-01"=double(),
          "2010-02"=double(),
          "2010-03"=double(),
          "2010-04"=double()
          )

df1<-rbind(df1,setNames(as.list(c(10,20,30,40)), names(df2)))

df2 <- data.frame("2010-01"=double(),
          "2010-02"=double(),
          "2010-03"=double(),
          "2010-04"=double()
          )

df2<-rbind(df2,setNames(as.list(c(100,200,300,400)), names(df2)))

df3 <- data.frame("2010-01"=double(),
          "2010-02"=double(),
          "2010-03"=double(),
          "2010-04"=double()
          )

df3<-rbind(df3,setNames(as.list(c(1000,2000,3000,4000)), names(df2)))

ui <-fluidPage(
 sidebarPanel(
   checkboxInput("add_data", "Add Data Table(s)"),
   conditionalPanel(condition="input.add_data === true",
             numericInput("numofdata",
                          label="Number of Data Table(s):",
                          min = 1,
                          max = 3,
                          value = 1,
                          step = 1),
             uiOutput("num_of_data"),
             textOutput("see_ranges")
            ),

    actionButton("submit", "Submit")
 ),

 mainPanel(

 titlePanel("Output Data Table"),

 DT::dataTableOutput("datatable.view", width = "95%")

 ) # end of main panel
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$num_of_data <- renderUI({
    lapply(1:input$numofdata, function(i) {
    print(trend_list())
  })
 })


 output$see_ranges <- renderPrint({
  print(trend_list())
 })

  data.filter <- reactive({

    df(i) 
  })

output$datatable.view <- DT::renderDataTable(
{
input$submit 
if (input$submit==0) return()

isolate({
for(i in 1:input$numoftrends) {
  datatable(data.filter(i), 
            rownames=FALSE,
            extensions = c("FixedColumns", "FixedHeader", "Scroller"), 
            options = list(searching=FALSE,
                           autoWidth=TRUE,
                           rownames=FALSE,
                           scroller=TRUE,
                           scrollX=TRUE,
                           pagelength=1,
                           fixedHeader=TRUE,
                           class='cell-border stripe',
                           fixedColumns = 
                          list(leftColumns=2,heightMatch='none')
                          )
          )
      }
  })
})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: What tables do you want to display? If the user selects `1`, do you want to show `df1`, if `2`, show `df1` and `df2` and in case of `3`, show all three? Is this limited to 3 tables only?

Comment: You code to create the datasets does not seem to work!

Comment: Hello- Yes I want to display df1 if user selects 1 and if he select 3 show all three df1 df2  and df3 . It is not limited to 3 tables. It can be more than that. I totally agree that my code does not work when the user try to display the dataframes. I am new to R and shiny and you help is very much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at this article:
http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/creating-a-ui-from-a-loop.html

You will seen then that one has to create multiple `renderDataTable` instead of muliple datatable within one `renderDataTable()`.
Also in your code you call `df` like a function `df()` but it is only defined as a variable.

See a generic running example below.
EDIT: Changed dynamic part of UI.

```
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("amountTable", "Amount Tables", 1:10, 3)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      # UI output
      uiOutput("dt")
    )
  )
)

server <-  function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    lapply(1:input$amountTable, function(amtTable) {
      output[[paste0('T', amtTable)]] <- DT::renderDataTable({
        iris[1:amtTable, ]
      })
    })
  })

  output$dt <- renderUI({
    tagList(lapply(1:input$amountTable, function(i) {
      dataTableOutput(paste0('T', i))
    }))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I am looking for. One question, though in your code that states "lapply(1:10, function(i) {", can I change that the 10 to input$amountTable instead.  This number depends on the user input.  I can have 10, 100, 1000. Appreciate it.

Comment: hi, sry didnt see the comment. Made a change to the code.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know I am asking too much. Is there a way that when a user initally select 3 for the Amount Tables, it will display 3 tables however if he decide to select 1 for the Amount Tables it will show only 1 table. Currently it is still showing 3 tables. It does clear the main panel. Appreciate your help on this

Comment: I think that should be possible with `removeUI()`. If you would need additional help that i would however suggest to ask a new question as it might get a bit difficult for others to track the changes then

Comment: Thank you , I would submit a new question. Have a great day!

Comment: wait a sec, check the code again, does it work for you with removing the tables after reducing the amount now?

Comment: When I ran your last code, it did not. But now with the new code it did.  Thanks. I am going to submit a new question  using this example where I can use the actionbutton to perform the submit and refresh, I'd like to know how to code the refresh action button. Thanks and have a great day!